# ChildVC's view not displaying correctly after pushViewController with autolayout iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout

My childViewController didn't display correctly after using pushViewController.

```
 // MainUI is subclass of NavigationController
 // MainUI has some navigationItems (<inbox,search,add)
 // SecondVC is DataLogsViewController (childVC)
 [MainUI pushViewController:SecondVC animated:YES];
```

This is how I setup my IB
[image]

When I run my code, As you can see the **PINK view wasn't shown**, my Guess is, its because of the navigationBar but I used autolayout I though autolayout would automatically handle this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Interface builder, while selecting your view controller uncheck "Under top Bars".

Comment: thanks for the idea dude, But It didn't do anything :(